# image processing

Tags: image, matlab

I have this set of images as shown, I found the centroid of each by using the code below, now I stored the new images in Im01,Im02,Im03, and they are all N by N matrix images.

```
Im1 = imread('image1.png');
[x,y] = ait_centroid(Im1);
Im01=circshift(Im1, [-1 -5]);
[x,y] = ait_centroid(Im01);
Im01=uint16(Im01);

Im2 = imread('image2.png');
[x,y] = ait_centroid(Im2);
Im02=circshift(Im2, [-2 -4]);
[x,y] = ait_centroid(Im02);
Im02=uint16(Im02);

Im3 = imread('image3.png');
[x,y] = ait_centroid(Im3);
Im03=circshift(Im3, [-3 -5]);
[x,y] = ait_centroid(Im03);
Im03=uint16(Im03);
```

my challenge is how to add this images using iteration cos i hav a large set of images(not jst the 3 images) im working on.I was able to add them manually n show the mean by doin this

```
G=imadd(Im01,Im02,'uint16');
G=imadd(G,Im03,'uint16');
imshow(uint8(G/3),[]);
```

and it worked.But when I tried iterating by doin this

```
G=imadd(Im01,Im02,'uint16');
for i=1:1:3
G=imadd(G,Im(i),'uint16');
end
```

I get error, I also tired to define the images as a matrix of a matrix by

```
H = [ [Im01] [Im02] [Im03] ]
G=imadd(Im01,Im02,'uint16');
for i=1:1:3
G=imadd(G,H(i),'uint16');
end
```

error indicates in H(i).

The code is in Matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`H = [ [Im01] [Im02] [Im03] ]` does not create an array of matrices in Matlab. Instead, it catenates the three images into a single array. What you want to do is create a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html), i.e. the following will work:

```
%# curly brackets to construct cell array
H = {Im01, Im02, Im03 }; 
G=H{1}; %# initialize G
for i=2:1:3 %# start at img#2
   G=imadd(G,H{i},'uint16');
end
```

Alternatively, if all you want to do with the images is to add them, you can do the following:

```
%# in case you want to store the images
images = cell(numberOfImages,1);

%# loop over all images
for iImg = 1:numberOfImages
   tmp = imread(sprintf('image%i.png',iImg));
   [x,y] = ait_centroid(tmp);
   Im01=circshift(tmp, [x y]); %# I assume that's what you want?
   [x,y] = ait_centroid(Im01); %# not sure what you do this for
   if iImg ==1
      G = uint16(tmp);
   else
      G = imadd(G,uint16(tmp));
   end
   %# maybe you want to store your images
   images{iImg} = uint16(tmp);
end
```

Comment: The first option is just perfect. The second didnt work bcos the circshift x and y values for each image varies.                       [x,y] = ait_centroid(Im01); I did it to verify that the centroid is same value for all the images before I add them.Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) and [eval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) to iterate over the names of your images.

```
G=imadd(Im01,Im02,'uint16');
for i=1:1:3
   Im_name = sprinft('Im0%i',i);    
   G=imadd(G,eval(Im_name),'uint16');
end
```

The sprintf function will add the number *i* behind the string 'Im0', so you will first get Im01, then Im02, etc.. The eval function is needed to interpret these strings into Matlab varibales.

EDIT: I think the best way to avoid problems like this is to save your images in a cell from the beginning. That is, when reading in the images, read them into one cell

```
Im{1} = imread('Im01.xxx')
Im{2} = imread('Im02.xxx')
etc...
```

you can then easily iterate over the different images without using strings.

Comment: I get error on line Im_name = sprinft('Im0%i',i); when I tried the first option, and for the second option,matlab cannot read the image because its no longer the original image in the directory, it has been edited, so its now stored as Im01,etc unlike Im1 wch can easily be read.